# Javascript - communicate with Lua script

Tags: javascript, lua, torch

I wonder what is a good way for Javascript to communicate with Lua script. I have my responsive front-end based on Bootstrap. What I want to do is send command data from Javascript to a Torch Lua script and get the return data from Lua.

The Lua script accepts input command like this in bash command line

```
$ input='{"data":[[20,21,22],[100, 101, 102]]}' th feed.lua
```

And it returns some data encoded in JSON.

Comment: I don't think reading your input from an environment variable is a good idea - Ideally you can make it into a FastCGI program, otherwise you could make it plain-old-cgi, mostly by rewriting it to use stdin/stdout instead.

Comment: @dualed Thanks for the input! I am going to use Waffle instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use [Waffle](https://github.com/benglard/waffle)
So far so good.